# Ways to protect site from external minified JS code

Tags: javascript, security

I understand the **best way** would be not to have the external JS at all, but alas, it's not possible.

**Situation**

The owner of a site wants (no ifs/ands/orButs) to get paid by a company that offers gambling ads. This company states that in order for them to offer said ads the owner of the site must add a **JS** code to the site. Said JS code is a few lines, but essentially it creates a tag `<script>` and loads a minified external JS file located in the publicity company's server. They do different kinds of ads (pop-ups, etc) and some other things that require the code.

There's no discussing **not** going through with this, I wanted to know if there were any kind of layers of security I might be able to add in order to protect site viewers. I know they are still in danger, but there's not much else I can do.

**Things to do**

- Copy the external JS file and serve it from site owner's server (or is that a horrible idea? The thing is, at least this way they can't be changing it to their heart's content, since it's in the site owner's server).
- Not loading the JS file in any page that has Login forms.
- Only load the JS file where the publicity will be shown.
- Not load the JS file is user if signed in
- Modify JS file so that it has its own scope `(function(){})()` .

Anything else I could possibly do? Or am I simply fooling myself in thinking I can offer some feeble protection?

Comment: Your todolist sounds great.

Comment: The only thing that seems sensible is the first: vet the script in a known state and refuse to serve any script you haven't vetted. Don't run code you don't trust, ever. How "vettable" it is is a different question of course…

Comment: @deceze I didn't add "vet" because the JS code is minified and obscured, for all I know that code is looking up <forms> and adding click events to everything. For me the way to go would be, don't add the JS file at all, but the site owner is not having that.

Comment: Another idea is to load said script into an iFrame, here you can control security..

Comment: @Keith I thought about that too, but I'd have to see if the company's popups and what nots still work.

Comment: @JonasW. "Sounds good, doesn't work" is the meme I'm thinking of right now. I feel like the piggy with the house of straw in the story.

Comment: Maybe [Subresource Integrity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity) helps.

Comment: Even in an iframe loaded from your site it can load other external scripts.
One way to intercept that is to replace document.write/writeln, but they can still add scripts to the head using DOM

Comment: @Occam'sRazor went ahead and edited for the word "Ads".

Comment: If the site's owner insists on using it, make sure he understands the potential consequences and move on. If he understands the consequences and wants to do it anyway, then let him. If I want to get a pile of shit tattooed on my forehead - that would be pretty stupid, but there are tons of people out there willing to take my money.

Comment: @str proposal IMHO is the best option.....

Comment: @Jordi That still doesn't help if you're not trusting the script you're including in the first place.

Comment: *"Modify JS file so that it has its own scope `(function(){})()`."* you can not prevent them breaking out of this scope and access everything that's in the global scope. So better ensure, that little of your stuff is available there.

Comment: @mplungjan An IFrame can be sandboxed -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe  Not 100% sure but I'm assuming this would stop any Cookie & Form extraction.

Comment: @deceze this is easier to solve.... you can request the code non minified, study it and approve its content... after this, you minify / uglify the given code in the same way the provider tells you and compare both miniuglyfied codes, if they match, get an integrity hash and trust it :)

Comment: @Thomas "*ensure that little of your stuff is available there*" - that doesn't help. It avoids unintentional conflicts, but if you don't trust the script you just must not run it at all.

Comment: @Jordi Yeah, [as I said…](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48868055/ways-to-protect-site-from-external-minified-js-code#comment84739585_48868055) :) Though whether that's "easier" is debatable.

Comment: heheheh @deceze well, maybe not an easy task... but at least sounds like a plan in this mess `:D`

Comment: In addition to everything that has already been said remember to 1) restrict access to your cookies setting `httpOnly` and `secure` flags; 2)  set approapriate security header, at least: `X-Frame-Options`, `X-XSS-Protection` and additionally `X-Content-Type-Options`, `Referrer-Policy` and `Strict-Transport-Security`

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways that may allow you to secure your page with external scripts.
First create a content security policy. This basically tells the browser where it can load different types of content from so if the third party starts loading content from new sources without telling you first they will be blocked.

Secondly the script-src tag. This allows you to specify a hash of the script tag and if it changes the browser won't run it.

There is a much better write up on these and more on Troy Hunt blog specifically this page https://www.troyhunt.com/locking-down-your-website-scripts-with-csp-hashes-nonces-and-report-uri/

Comment: Still, none of this helps if you aren't trusting the script you're directly including.

Answer (score 0):

### Things to do:

- Use a CDN that supports versions (almost every modern CDNs supports that) so you don't need to host these JS files yourself, and you don't need to worry about the fact that the file might change.
- Only run your JS on login pages
- For ads, use `iframe` elements, so the JS code for ads can't access external information
- Use Subresource Integrity (SRI) on script tags

*Example with jQuery*

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

- As Karl Graham mentioned, use [Content Security Policy (CSP)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) in an HTTP Header, so content can't leak.
- Make sure to use SSL Certificates (HTTPS), and to encrypt content when you do AJAX/Fetch requests so even if an external script listens to `FetchEvents`, it won't be able to read the data.

I'm almost certain that if you follow these rules, your external script won't be able to get your form content.

Comment: But it could possibly show any horrible content. I loaded a normal Dutch newspaper on my iPad and had a hardcore porn popup from an Iframed ad.

Comment: "*you don't need to worry about the fact that the file might change*" - using a CDN does not mitigate that worry

Comment: "*Only run your JS on login pages*" - how is that supposed to help anything?

Comment: @Bergi yes, that's why using SRI is useful

Comment: @mplungjan Yes, true, but there is no way of fixing this issue (you could use ad block, but not everyone is using ad block).